# Fabric.js - re-build and commercial use

Tags: fabricjs

I have used Fabric.js as core canvas library for a recent project, and it's commercial one, To reduce the bandwidth, I am planing to remove some modules in Fabric.js and re-build it. Now my question is the project is a commercial product, so is Fabric.js licensee allow that re-build thing, and did I need to open source the new build Fabric.js too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fabric is licensed under MIT.

Feel free to modify it as you wish for personal or commercial reasons.

You can create a custom Fabric build either [on a site](http://fabricjs.com/build) or via command line, on your machine (requires Node.js).

Comment: Thank you, that's nice help.